# how to add function current score to final score with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addition, addeventlistener

sorry for need your help but I can't resolve this problem...

i've got a current score who's changing when I click on button with id "roll".
When I click on this button the random number is add to the old current score (it's good for me)

the problem is here: when I click on "hold" button, I want the result of all the addition of the current score go to the id="score"
And I can't do that.

I need your help to find the solution please.

this is a part of my html code:

```
            <h3 class="ion-text-center">
              Score
            </h3>
            <div class="ion-text-center" id="score">
              0
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row  id="bottomRow">
          <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
            <div>CURRENT</div>
            <div id="currentScore">0</div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
            <button class="favorite styled" type="button" id="roll" onclick="rollDice()">
            Lancer le dé
            </button>
            <button class="favorite styled" type="button" id="hold">
            Réserver
            </button>
```

and this is my js code:

```
//création of random number
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min+1) ) + min;
}


// functions for current score 
let loseScore = 0;
let addCurrentScore = 0;


function currentScoreLose(){
  alert ("Vous avez perdu")
  document.getElementById("currentScore").textContent = loseScore;
  addCurrentScore = 0;
}


function addCurrentScoreFunction(){
  let randomNumber = getRandomInt(1, 6);
  if (randomNumber === 1){
    currentScoreLose();
  } else {
    alert (randomNumber)
    addCurrentScore += randomNumber;
    document.getElementById("currentScore").textContent = addCurrentScore;
    let goodScore = document.getElementById("currentScore").textContent;
    return goodScore;
  }
}


//this function add current score to final score when we click on id hold
let score = document.getElementById("score");

function add (){
  score.textContent += addCurrentScoreFunction(goodScore);
}


//here we call functions
let roll = document.getElementById("roll");
let hold = document.getElementById("hold");

roll.addEventListener("click", addCurrentScoreFunction);
hold.addEventListener("click", add);
```

[picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7jG4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variable scope nightmare, but here's my quick take on what you're trying to do. Probably needs some tweaks for lose and what should happen for reserve.

```js
//création of random number
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// functions for current score 
let currentScore = 0;
let reserveScore = 0;

function currentScoreLose() {
  alert("Vous avez perdu")
  document.getElementById("currentScore").textContent = loseScore;
  currentScore = 0;
}


function rollDice() {
  let randomNumber = getRandomInt(1, 6);
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    currentScoreLose();
  } else {
    console.log(randomNumber);
    currentScore += randomNumber;
    console.log(currentScore);
    document.getElementById("currentScore").textContent = currentScore;
  }
}

function reserve() {
  reserveScore += currentScore;
  console.log(reserveScore);
  document.getElementById("reserveScore").textContent = reserveScore;
}


//here we call functions
let roll = document.getElementById("roll");
let hold = document.getElementById("hold");

roll.addEventListener("click", rollDice);
hold.addEventListener("click", reserve);
```

```html
<span>Score</span>
<span id="reserveScore">0</span>
<br>
<span>CURRENT</span>
<span id="currentScore">0</span>
<br><br>
<button class="favorite styled" type="button" id="roll">
Roll the dice
</button>

<button class="favorite styled" type="button" id="hold">
Reserve
</button>
```

Comment: I must change details in your code for delete current score when we click on reserveScore, but it's perfect to add currentscore to reserve score, great thanck !!!